# py2exe not finding modules already installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I'm trying to use p2exe to build an exe from a python script that uses pymodbus and twisted (with lots of underlying dependencies apparently). I can build the exe but it does not run properly. I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong setting up the environment. I'm confident it is not my script because I can run it just fine from the python command line interpreter.

My python script uses these modules...

```
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
import sys
import logging
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
```

I get this error on python setup1.py py2exe...

```
The following modules appear to be missing 
['Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath', 'FCNTL', 'OpenSSL', 'OpenSSL.SSL',   'OpenSSL._util', 'PAM', 'System', 'System.IO.Ports', 'TERMIOS', '_scproxy',
'gmpy', 'idna', 'pkg_resources', 'pyasn1.codec.ber', 'pyasn1.error', 'pyasn1.type', 'queue', 'resource', 'service_identity', 'service_identity
.pyopenssl', 'twisted.python._initgroups', 'twisted.python.sendmsg']
```

It builds the exe. When I run the exe this happens...

```
C:\Users\jlaird\Desktop\slush\dbclienttest\dist>modbus_slave2.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "modbus_slave2.py", line 1, in <module>
File "pymodbus\server\async.pyc", line 18, in <module>
File "pymodbus\internal\ptwisted.pyc", line 5, in <module>
File "twisted\conch\manhole_ssh.pyc", line 14, in <module>
File "twisted\conch\ssh\factory.pyc", line 15, in <module>
File "twisted\conch\ssh\transport.pyc", line 32, in <module>
File "twisted\conch\ssh\keys.pyc", line 20, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.error
```

If I start python and do 'import pyasn1' it imports without error. I can also import twisted and pymodbus just fine. Python can reach it but not py2exe. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...for some reason the contents of the build\lib folder for pyasn1 was not copied into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. Only an egg was copied. So I moved the folder over into site-packages and py2exe built an executable that worked.